# Show the map $(T\phi)(x) = \phi(Ax+b)$ is well-defined on $\mathcal{D}(R^n)$ and $T$ is continuous.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Show that the map $(T\phi)(x) = \phi(Ax+b)$ is well-defined on $\mathcal{D}(R^n)$ and $T$ is continuous, with $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n},\; det(A)\neq 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Here arise the questions:

1) What does it means that $T$ is well defined on $\mathcal{D}(R^n)$? My guess is that I have to prove that $T$ is in $\mathcal{D}(R^n)$. But supposing $\phi \in \mathcal{D}(R^n)$, then $T$ is automatically in $\mathcal{D}(R^n)$ because $x \mapsto Ax+b$ is a simple translation.

2) To show that $T$ is continous I have to prove that if $\phi_k \rightarrow \phi$ in $\mathcal{D}(R^n)$, with $\{\phi_k\}$ in $\mathcal{D}(R^n)$ then it must be that $T\phi_k \rightarrow T\phi$ in $\mathcal{D}(R^n)$?

Comment: 11) $x\to Ax+b$ is not a simple translation, you have a matrix $A$ here. You need to prove that $\phi(Ax+b) \in D(\Bbb R^n)$; (2) exactly.

Comment: For the point one, I have to check only the support of $T\phi$: define $(T\phi)(x) = \phi(Ax+b) \equiv \psi$. Then $x \in \text{supp}(\psi) \Leftrightarrow Ax+b \in \text{supp}(\phi) \Rightarrow x \in A^{-1}(\text{supp}(\phi)) - A^{-1}b$ which is compact. Is that right?

Comment: It is, up to a clarification why $A^{-1}(supp (\phi) - \{b\})$ is compact.